# Could "News Feed Items" in chat auto dismiss when you click them?

Tags: feature-request, chat, feed

#### The scenario:

You're in chat. Someone posts a question in the stack to which your chat belongs. A little box pops up in the top left with the question, stacking up to several times if more than one question has been asked.

Given that, if I click on one of the questions, it opens in a new tab and I can read it to my hearts content. When I go back to my chat tab, the question is still there.

#### The ask:

Can we dismiss individual news feed items when they get clicked on?

#### example

[image]